# Sending download request to web client using nodejs

Tags: node.js, download, webclient

I am implementing some downloader application. Web client will send some data in web server. 
It will process the data and will create a file in some specific format and will push that file to client.
I have done the part till creating the file using nodeJS. 
Now can someone suggest me how I can push the file to the client. It is like a downloader application, whenever web client sends the data, using some upload button, it will open a Save As window to save the file in client machine.

So can someone throw some light or pointer on some existing code stuff such that I can have a look?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

-M-

Answer (score 0):

You can see how do the Express Framework implement that:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L356

Line 364: Set the `Content-Disposition` header to tell the client this response is a attachment that can be downloaded.

```
this.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + basename(filename) + '"');
```

Line 365: Send the file as the body of the response:

```
return this.sendfile(path, fn);
```

The `send` module is used in the above function:
https://github.com/visionmedia/send